# Why am I receiving a RangeError at compile time in this app?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey there and thank you in advance for any possible assistance.

With the following code, I'm receiving a RangeError. Anyone know why that would be?
I'm not seeing any reference out side the range that should be caught at compile time. I know that the user could potentially press the button more than once and it would generate an error (I'm just following along in a tutorial and we'll address that later), but that wasn't caught at compile time on the tutorial.

Is there some additional compile time validations that is coming in with the newer versions of Flutter or Dart that may be causing this?

Again, Thank you for any assistance.

**======== Exception caught by widgets library =====================================================
The following RangeError was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 4**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState  extends State<MyApp> {
  var questionIndex = 0;

  void answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      "What's your favorite color?",
      "What's your favorite animal?",
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Text( questions[questionIndex] ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Answer'),
            onPressed: answerQuestion,
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Because the length of your questions has a limit... and you keep increasing an integer value without having that in consideration

Comment: This line looks suspicious. `questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;` what happens if you bounds check this against the length of `questions`?

Comment: Also isn't this a runtime error?

Comment: It would be best to just handle the `RangeError` and follow along with the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

As you want to increase the question number on pressing the button. You should call the function on pressing the button.
So change

```
RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Answer'),
        onPressed:() { answerQuestion() },
      )
```

Comment: onPressed: takes a function as input.If you add the parenthesis to the end of answerQuestion, you are no longer passing the function, but instead passing the return value from the function.

Comment: Oh! Yes it should be like this- onPressed:() { answerQuestion() }

Comment: ``(`` and ``)`` are called parenthesis !!